# Where’s the indie self-publishing site?

Tags: feature-request, site-recommendation

I got a question about *missing sites* and am hoping this is the right place to ask. FYI: I don’t see a meta link on the closest existing site, so here goes:

Under “Professional” you’ve got “[Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/tour)” (...“for the craft of professional writing, including fiction,...”), but where’s “Publishing” or “Self-Publishing” or “Independent Self-Publishing”? This is similar to *Writing*, but it adds the business side plus the latest in self-publishing that’s been brought on by Amazon, et. al. Would it be possible to add?

Answer (score 7):

There aren't any publishing, self-publishing, or independent self-publishing sites at the moment. If you'd like to propose one, go to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/); more specifically, to the '[Proposals](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=professional)' button on the 'Professional' tab.

However, the [writing.stackexchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) site has a [[self-publishing]](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-publishing) tag, which should hopefully be enough for your purposes.

[ebooks.stackexchange](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/) also an [[independent-publishing]](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/independent-publishing) tag as well, which may be useful if you're looking to self-publish in that area.

Comment: Thanks. Area 51 is a bit complicated but I'll investigate. Didn't know about the [self-publishing] tag. That's something, although I think it should be its own site.

Comment: @eHaraldo - I hope you find what you need; just be sure to read the site's [FAQ section](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) before you start, particularly the part titled '_Should my idea be part of an existing site, or its own site?_' :)